# Don't open popup menu when running help in R console

Tags: r, config

When I am running R in a (linux) terminal und call e.g. (With pkgload installed)

```
> help(help)
```

a popup menu is opened, where I have to select whether I want to see the help page from the `pkgload` or the `utils` package.

I would like R to not open a popup menu but let me select with numbers (1, 2, ...) which of the help pages I want to see.

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the text menu by running

```
options(menu.graphics = FALSE)
```

beforehand.